# Python: How to have to change a variable once, and never change it again

Tags: gnome, python, gtk, glade

```
flub = raw_input("Where would you like your save directory to be?)
SaveDir = flub
```

Hello ubuntu, I am writing a python program. My question is, how can I make it so a raw_input asks me a question that defines a variable (in this case variable is flub), then changes the code so that the variable is always the same. When I change the flub variable in the program, I would like it to always remember what I changed the variable to.

Note: this code is just an example, I am really working with an advanced program with a graphical interface, and I didn't want to post it here on the ubuntu fourms. If you have any questions, please ask.

Thanks ubuntu :)

Comment: I would assign your variable to a constant after acquiring your variable and using the constant for the remainder of the program so something like: what is x?; x = 1, constant = x, y = constant * 5 or something like that. follow the logic not the code lol, I know it isn't right.

Comment: I am not pretty sure, but since python is dynamically typed, I don't think you can do what you are trying to. There is no `const` in python and the interpreter too does not enforce type checking, so I believe this rather might have workarounds (which I am not aware of though) than solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes @Tim, it should, but you see. Many years ago, I posted a question that got many bad reviews, and now I am no longer allowed to post on StackOverflow :(

Comment: @Mezex you have 6, and haven't  been banned by the look of it, so you should be able too.  None of them have been voted down that much...

Comment: @Mezex Please don't double post the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

    `flub = raw_input('Where would you like your save directory to be?')
    print flub`

Will get your variable, pass that to your GUI.

Unless you change it later on in the program, it will remain until restarted / retriggered. To store that value permanently, you would need to write it somewhere lets say a text file, or set your program up to set a true false checking whether that variable has been set yet.

Comment: This doesn't help me. I may not have been specific enough. What I need is for that input to change the variable, then no matter if the program is restarted, or the computer is shut down, the variable will not change again.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand slightly, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830334/change-variable-permanently saving to a text file for reference like this is what I meant

Comment: Also, as far I understand it, once a Python program is loaded, you can write to it. You could set flub manually, by having Python overwrite those lines in its code with the updated variable. THen just check to see if flub was set before asking. That should do it.

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I got it from that link you gave me. Thanks for the help! @Duncubuntu